# How do I resolve SVN error "E200030: There are unfinished transactions detected in '<CHECKOUT_DIRECTORY>'"?

Tags: eclipse, windows, svn, subversive, svnkit

I have installed a virtual box with Windows 10, Eclipse Mars, Subversive Plugin, SVNKit 1.8.11 and tried to set up some repositories in a configuration I already did successfully in several other environments. The SVN server is a Debian 7 system with Subversion 1.6.17. The following problem occurs only since I set up the above mentioned system:

1. Check-out: e. g. SVN-Repositories -> expand Repository X -> right-click on trunk -> check-out -> Error occurs: "Checkout operation for 'svn://host/X/trunk' failed. svn: E200030: There are unfinished transactions detected in 'C:\PathToWorkspace\X'"
2. After this the Subversive plugin stops working, apparently.
3. Export: same result as check-out

Further investigation got me to a specific file in the repository, which fails loading with "invalid handle" error. It is not in a "strange" path (not too long, no spaces or special characters) and the file itself contains no suspicious characters, just Unix line breaks. Permissions and space on disk are OK. Other respositories with the same properties DO work as expected.

I found posts with similar problems, but none of them applied to mine, apparently. They told me to wipe my workspace directory (which I did), but I just lost all of my settings without solving the problem. After this, I investigated the program directory of Eclipse, whicht didn't bring any more success.

Additionally, the ".svn\wc.db" file is still locked after the failure. Deleting the repository is therefore not possible until closing Eclipse. The directory is not listed in any project list/tree in eclipse like the package explorer, but the directory exists on the disk.

The same repository X still works in every of the other configurations I have. How can I reset these "transactions" in order to repair this? I really would like to avoid completely reinstalling Eclipse or even Windows.

**EDIT**
I istalled TortoiseSVN 1.16.16.21511 (x64), which perfectly fits to the SVN service version. Same problem.

Comment: This might be related to a problem I found when using TortoiseSVN with TeamCity checkout folders, and could be a bug. Try switch off icon overlays in Tortoise using settings as a workaround. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652124/teamcity-svn-agent-side-checkout-fails-with-error-svn-e200030-there-are-unfini

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it: creating the files "con.cpp" and "con.h" from the project had apparently been rejected by Windows. As far as I remember, "con" is kind of a reserved command or sub command in Windows. Renaming it to something else right in the repository solved the problem.

Answer (score 29):

First, try:

- Right-click the project -> Team -> Cleanup.

If that didn't help:

- Restart Eclipse -> Team -> Cleanup

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I tried this already. In this particular case the problem was the filename "con", which isn't allowed in Windows filesystems. Cleanup simply gave me the same error message.

Comment: restarting was the solution

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error in my case but in different situation, I was working on the shared folder using both Eclipse and Tortoise SVN, and Eclipse was not able to clean up or do any commit, so I tried to close Eclipse and do clean up from outside using tortoise. it worked.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 4):

> When you are performing any team operations in eclipse ( such as
>   commit, update, replace ) and if you cancel the operation in between.
>   The files involved in the operation are locked.

This is one of the possibilities for the error to appear.

To resolve this in Eclipse.

```
Right Click on the project -> Team -> Cleanup
```

If the above process doesn't work

```
Restart eclipse -> Right Click on the project -> Team -> Cleanup
```

If this didn't resolve the issue.

Remove these locks explicitly.

**Ubuntu**

Install svn if you haven't installed.

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Then clean the project folder.

```
svn cleanup /path/to/working-copy
```

**Windows**

Get Tortise SVN from this [link](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html).

1. After installing, Right-click on the project folder which is linked to SVN.
2. There will be an option do SVN cleanup. Click on it. It takes some time to clean up. 
   Then you are good to go.

This solution worked for me.

Comment: For me when I interrupted a large revision which went wrong, using the eclipse Team->cleanup didn't work bu this did.

Answer (score 0):

i had an error also on the command 'cleanup' on a project, and restarting the eclipse didn't solve.
i had to disconnect the project from svn and re-connect later

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, unfortunately, the issue with the device storage running out of memory.
Free up the memory and able to  proceed further from the mentioned issue

Answer (score 0):

I have Eclipse Luna with Subversive, and I had two problems to syncronize with the Repository in a Server, E170001 and E20030 (sometines one and sometimes both). My solution was:

1.- In Eclipse: go to to "Window" - "Preferences".
2.- Go to "General" - "Network Connections".

Down, at Proxy Bypass, add de IP of the server where you has the Repository of SVN.