# TeamCity SVN agent-side checkout fails with error svn: E200030: There are unfinished transactions detected in folder

Tags: svn, teamcity, tortoisesvn, svnkit

After upgrading to TeamCity 2017.2 my SVN checkout began failing on my build agent with this error:

svn: E200030: There are unfinished transactions detected in '[... folder ...]'

The agent is running on Windows Server 2012 R2 and TeamCity Professional 2017.2 (build 50574)

Initial Googling and browsing on Stack Overflow didn't find an answer yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After further Googling I found this bug on the TeamCity YouTrack:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-49325 specifically this comment https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-49325#comment=27-2472122

I had TortoiseSVN 1.9 installed on the build agent.

Disabling the Tortoise icon overlays for my build agent folders under Settings -> Icon Overlays -> Exclude Paths allowed my checkout to continue successfully again.

> Looks like the problem is caused by a TortoiseSVN client when it monitors SVN folders,

Comment: I logged https://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-717 on the SVNKit issue tracker to try find out if it is a SVNKit bug. Also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisesvn/CH3R1LmZ1gw on the Tortoise user Google group

Comment: As an update, SVNKit and Jetbrains have both released patches to deal with the issue. I will confirm whether the issue is fixed when I next upgrade TeamCity.

Comment: I had the same issue with TeamCity Professional 8.1.1 (build 29939) and this solution worked like a charm!